# Install directory for Notepad++ Plugin Manager on Mac

Tags: macos, notepad++, wine

After successfully installing Notepad++ on my Mac using Winebottler, I was pleased to see that many of the plugins install just fine using the Plugin Manager.  A few plugins such as Compare seem to need a bit of additional tweaking however in order to be used easily.

Upon looking into the Plugin Manager settings this appears to be the target path for installs --

**Expected Path:** `C:\users\<your_name>\Application Data\Notepad++\plugins\Config`

**Investigated Path:** `/Applications/Notepad++.app/Contents/Resources/wineprefix/drive_c/users/<your_name>/Application Data/Notepad++/plugins/config`

When navigating to the investigated path above the folder contents appear empty.  Nothing appears even after enabling hidden files.

Where else would these plugins would be installed for Notepad++ on a Mac (using Wine)?

Answer (score 0):

I have two editors on my Mac that I use regularly, Atom and VScode. Both of these have a directory located in my home directory. These are .atom and .vscode. In both cases any modules or extensions are stored the the respective folder.

Comment: A good thought, but installing Windows programs on a Mac using Winebottler and the Wine translation engine generally requires that the files are placed in destinations that mimic a Windows folder structure